# Surfaceview and UI thread interactions and locking game variables

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview updates/draws on canvas by a thread. I thought UI thread (user interactions) and surfaceview thread do not have interactions because of surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null). I thought the logic of these threads are synchronized. But when I loged user touch events and surfaceview thread update logic, they seemed to be running simultaneously in some instances.
**See following log, which should ACTION_MOVE end happens after update.**

Because of this issues there is no way to safely update game variables from UI thread (based on user tough events) and then update the canvas on surface view. How to resolve this issue? is there away to lock/ synchronize game variables so we can access them safely between two threads?

```
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end
 D/myApp﹕ update
 **D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ update
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end**
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end
 D/myApp﹕ update
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end
 D/myApp﹕ update
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end
 D/myApp﹕ update
 D/myApp﹕ update
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE start
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE
 D/myApp﹕ ACTION_MOVE end
 D/myApp﹕ update




public class GameThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GameViewSurface surface;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Context GameContext;
    private int gameState;
    public static final int STATE_PAUSE = 1;
    public static final int STATE_RUNNING = 2;

    private int GameSurfaceWidth = 1;
    private int GameSurfaceHeight = 1;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder holder, Context context, GameViewSurface GameSurface) {
        surfaceHolder = holder;
        surface = GameSurface;
        GameContext = context;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    public void startGame() {
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            setState(STATE_RUNNING);
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            if (gameState == STATE_RUNNING) setState(STATE_PAUSE);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void restoreState(Bundle savedState) {
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            setState(STATE_PAUSE);
        }
    }

    public void setState(int stateToSet) {
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            // TODO Message Handling
        }
    }

    public Bundle saveState(Bundle map) {
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            if (map != null) {

            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        // synchronized to make sure these all change atomically
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            GameSurfaceWidth = width;
            GameSurfaceHeight = height;
        }
    }

    public void unpause() {
        setState(STATE_RUNNING);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Canvas canvas=null;
            try {

                if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                surface.update();

                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                    surface.doDraw(canvas);
                }
            } catch(Exception p){

                Log.d("myApp", p.getMessage());

            }finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



public class GameViewSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


    public GameViewSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        gameThread = new GameThread(getHolder(), context, this);

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        if (!hasWindowFocus) gameThread.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
       // gameThread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        gameThread.setRunning(true);
        gameThread.start();
        createGameHandler();
    }

    public void createGameHandler()
    {
        gameData = new Game(backColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        gameThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                gameThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }


    //@Override
    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(gameDataGen.board, mPosX, mPosY, null);


    }

    public void playSound() {
        if (enableSound && !sp.isPlaying())
            sp.start();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        try {

            if (waitTillLoad || isExit || finished)
                return;
            if (gameData != null) {
                gameData.update();

            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        viewHeight = h;
        viewWidth = w;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if(waitTillLoad ||finished || !isTouchable || bypassParent)
           return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        boolean handled = false;
        int xTouch;
        int yTouch;
        int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();

        // get touch event coordinates and make transparent circle from it
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("myApp", "ACTION_DOWN start");
                xTouch = (int) event.getX(0);
                yTouch = (int) event.getY(0);

                if (scaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    break;
                 }

                 mLastTouchX = xTouch;
                 mLastTouchY = yTouch;

                this.selectedIndex = findClusterFromXY(xTouch, yTouch);
                if (selectedIndex >= 0) {

                    Log.d("myApp", "ACTION_DOWN selectedIndex >");

                    gameData.setTopIndex(this.selectedIndex);
                    gameData.clearMotionData();
                    gameData.addMotionEvent(new Point(xTouch, yTouch));

                }
                handled = true;
                Log.d("myApp", "ACTION_DOWN end");
                break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                xTouch = (int) event.getX();
                yTouch = (int) event.getY();
                gameData.moveStart = true;
                gameData.moveEnd = false;



                    gameData.setMovingClusterData(gameData.currentCluster);
                    gameData.addMotionEvent(new Point(xTouch, yTouch));
                    _previousMouseX = xTouch;
                    _previousMouseY = yTouch;


                Log.d("myApp", "ACTION_MOVE end");
                gameData.moveEnd = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("myApp", "ACTION_UP start");
                handled = processActionUp(event, true);

                handled = true;
                Log.d("myApp", "ACTION_UP end");
                break;

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    protected void onComplete() {
        if(solveFragment != null)
        {
            finished= true;
            solveFragment.onComplete();
        }
    }

    public GameThread getThread() {
        return gameThread;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hard to say without an example of your code... Perhaps you need to re-think your design. Should the UI thread be directly updating the variables? Maybe you could use an event queue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you mean have a list to collect all events and process it in the thread logic sequentially. But that is a variable too, how do we lock it otherwise we ll end up with the same issue.

I have added the code now. GameViewSurface has update and doDraw which executes inside the Game thread. DoDraw uses user Touch up down move and gesture coming from UI thread to draw on canvas.

Comment: You didn't add any code :-)

Comment: my edits have vanished. Anyway I have given cut down version above. gameData object retains data used to update the image drawn on canvas. gameData also keep track of user touch actions. Issue is how to synchronize game thread and UI on this object. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach listed in following page worked for me.

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/342-using-input-pipelines-your-android-game

Use a properly locked pipeline (Queue) to store the current user events. Then process the items in this list one by one when Surfaceview thread executes.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please describe the essence of the solution in the answer.